# Images overlapping and drawing twice

Tags: c#, xna

I have a cloud and a man sprite, these are both drawn separately but for some reason they are drawing together and overlapping and then positioning themselves at the defined places for both of the sprites.

My sprites class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace MarioFake
{
class Sprites
{

    public Vector2 MarioPosition = new Vector2(200, 200);
    private Texture2D MarioStill;

    public Vector2 LargeCloudPosition = new Vector2(100, 100);
    private Texture2D LargeCloud;

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager theContentManager, string theAssetName)
    {
        MarioStill = theContentManager.Load<Texture2D>(theAssetName);
        LargeCloud = theContentManager.Load<Texture2D>(theAssetName);
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch theSpriteBatch)
    {
        theSpriteBatch.Draw(MarioStill, MarioPosition, Color.White);
        theSpriteBatch.Draw(LargeCloud, LargeCloudPosition, Color.White);
    }

}
}
```

and my drawing method in my Game class:

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        MarioStill.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
        LargeCloud.Draw(this.spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sprite class doesn't need to hold information for both Mario and the cloud, if you create a generic sprite class like this ..

```
  public class Sprite
    {
        public Vector2 Location;
        public Texture2D Texture;

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Location, Color.White);
        }
    }
```

you can create your mario and clouds like this.

```
Sprite Mario = new Sprite() { Location = new Vector2(200, 200), Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("MarioTexture") };
Sprite Cloud = new Sprite() { Location = new Vector2(100, 100), Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("CloudTexture") };
```

and draw them as you previously did.

```
            Mario.Draw(spriteBatch);
            Cloud.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

Here is an example of a full game class that demonstrates loading and rendering both sprites.

```
 public class Sprite
    {
        public Vector2 Location;
        public Texture2D Texture;

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Location, Color.White);
        }
    }

    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        List<Sprite> sprites;

        Sprite mario, cloud;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // Create the sprites.            
            sprites = new List<Sprite>();
            mario = new Sprite() { Location = new Vector2(100, 100), Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("MarioTexture") };
            cloud = new Sprite() { Location = new Vector2(200, 200), Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("CloudTexture") };
            sprites.Add(mario);
            sprites.Add(cloud);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            foreach (var sprite in sprites)
                sprite.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would that not mean for every single image I would have to have        `Sprite Cloud = new Sprite() { Location = new Vector2(100, 100), Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("CloudTexture") }`

Comment: Or similar for every sprite i want to load

Comment: There is also the issue of loading the content.

Comment: Yes it would but the texture properties can all point to the same texture if mario and the cloud are both together.

Comment: I'll give you a slightly better demo game class.

Comment: I've updated the answer, if you have both images on one texture (you really should) then let me know and I'll update to allow for that.